# Generate range of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import string
def charRange(mini, maxi, step=1):
  if mini in string.ascii_uppercase:
    strg = string.ascii_uppercase
  else:
    strg = string.ascii_lowercase
  return (strg[i] for i in 
          range(string.ascii_lowercase.index(mini.lower()),
                string.ascii_lowercase.index(maxi.lower())+1,
                step))
```

Examples of usage:

```
for i in charRange('A', 'Z'):
    print(i)
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
for i in charRange('a', 'h'):
  print(i, end=' ')
> a b c d e f g h
for i in charRange('A', 'J', 2):
  print(i, end=' ')
> A C E G I
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you would operate with *character code ranges* and use the [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) and [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) built-in functions instead:

```
def char_range(mini, maxi, step=1):
    for code in range(ord(mini), ord(maxi) + 1, step):
        yield chr(code)
```

Or, with the [`yield from`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) (Python 3.3+):

```
def char_range(mini, maxi, step=1):
    yield from range(ord(mini), ord(maxi) + 1, step)
```

Demo:

```
$ ipython3 -i test.py
In [1]: for char in char_range('a', 'h'):
   ...:     print(char, end=' ')
   ...:     
a b c d e f g h
```

Couple notes about the code style of your solution:

- according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), there should be two blank lines after the imports
- use the "lower_case_with_underscores" style to name the function - `charRange()` vs `char_range()` ([PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions))

Comment: There is a yield from statement in python 3, so you can modify your generator a bit to make it use it.

Comment: @Alex yeah, good idea, included that to the answer as well. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know about yield from; it's awesome!